# Items outside of the app's screen are getting cut off when scrolled back into screen

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to have a parallax moving background of images behind my actual content. I have added a converter according to John's solution:
http://w8isms.blogspot.com/2012/09/parallax-background-in-xaml-revisited.html

The parallax scrolling part is working fine, although I have stumbled upon a following problem - images outside of the initial app's screen area get cut off, so when I scroll to the right, only white area starts to appear instead of the rest of the images, as in the content of those would have to be redrawn. Does anybody have a clue as to what I could do to fix it?

This is my code:

```
<Grid Background="White">        
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform
               TranslateX="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer, Path=HorizontalOffset, Converter={StaticResource ParallaxConverter}}" />
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <Image Source="1.jpg"/>
        <Image Source="2.jpg"/>
        <Image Source="3.jpg"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer
       x:Name="MyScrollViewer"
       HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
       HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="180"
           Text="Hello world! This text will extend to the right." />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Had to wrap my StackPanel inside a Canvas element.